# mvc + partial view + check box click event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created a partial view and using it in same page for `n` times. The partial view is placed inside a accordion (`div`), and when a checkbox is clicked, then text box should be disabled.

When I render the page, which uses the partial view 5 times, and I click the checkbox, then the textbox gets disabled only within the first partial view.  The same functionality doesn't work in any of the others.

When I place the debugger in all the partial views it hits, but the textbox doesn't get disabled.  This only works in the 1st partial view, but fails in the rest.

Please find the below code..

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Select Recurrance:</th>
        <th>Start DateTime:</th>
        <th>End DateTime:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="margin-top: -0.0em;">
                <select id="Recurrances" onchange="SubmitRecurrance(this)">
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">Run Continuosly</option>
                    <option value="2">Run on Schedule</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recurrance)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="margin-top: -0.0em;">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDateTime, new { @class = "form-control date-picker", @placeholder = "Start Date&Time", id = "starttime", onkeyup = "FormDirty();" })
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDateTime)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="margin-top: -0.0em;">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDateTime, new { @class = "form-control date-picker", @placeholder = "End Date&Time", id = "endtime", onkeyup = "FormDirty();" })
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDateTime)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="divnoenddate">
            <div>
                <span> No End Date</span>@Html.CheckBox("NoEndDate", false, new { id = "noenddate", onchange = "javascript:ChangeCheckBox()" })
                <br />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="recureveryoption">
            <span style="font-weight:bold;">Recur Every:</span> <div>
                <select id="RecurEvery">
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">Daily</option>
                    <option value="2">Weekly</option>
                    <option value="3">Monthly</option>
                    <option value="4">Yearly</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" style=" width: 8em;height: 2em;text-align: center;padding-top: 6px;background: #0082BF;font-size: 1em; color: #0082BF; cursor:pointer; color:white;font-size: 1em; padding-left:6px; padding-right:6px;padding-bottom:6px;" onclick="SubmitChanges()" />
             </div>
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>

function ChangeCheckBox()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("Recurrances").value != 1)
        {
            debugger;
            if (document.getElementById('noenddate').checked == true)
            {
                document.getElementById("endtime").disabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("endtime").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm referring the above partial view as:

```
<div>
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Settings/ScedularControl.cshtml") 
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide more details, code or fiddle etc...

Comment: Can you show us the HTML with the checkbox(es) and the Javascript that goes with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sent to parameter index of partial view than use checkbox like, following html helper list item:

```
@Html.CheckBox("SameModel["+index+"].Checked",false)
```